# Function no recoge remove, add, etc

Tags: javascript

Con este poco codigo que tengo, estaba intentando cambiar el valor de CSS a un div llamado td en su class, un mouseover que redirige a cambiarCSS y lo que se puede leer dentro. Este recogelos datos que yo quiero que coga en el console.log lo he comprobado, pero a pesar de que parece que todo es correcto, ponga la funcion que ponga me devuelve todo el rato esto: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'remove')
at cambiarCSS.

El codigo es el siguiente:

HTML

```
<div class="td" onmouseover="cambiarCSS()">fsdghsdfdf</div>
```

JS

```
function cambiarCSS(){

        var button = document.querySelectorAll(".td");
        console.log(button);
        button.classList.remove("td");
        button.classList.add("tdHover");

    };
```

Muchas gracias a todos de antemano!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Si no quieres utilizar un id para identificar al div, y quieres tener más div con esa clase (.td), tienes que tener en cuenta que [querySelectorAll()](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll) devuelve un [NodeList](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/NodeList) que es no es un arreglo pero si es iterable, con esto puedes hacer algo como:

```js
function cambiarCSS(){
  var buttons = document.querySelectorAll(".td");
  for (var i = 0; i < buttons.length; i++) {
    buttons[i].classList.remove("td");
    buttons[i].classList.add("tdhover")
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="td" onmouseover="cambiarCSS()">fsdghsdfdf</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

para cambiar la clase deberías usar un id por ejemplo

```
<div class="td" id="td" onmouseover="cambiarCSS()">fsdghsdfdf</div>
```

y ya con el ID ya funcionaria tu js

```
function cambiarCSS(){

    var button = document.getElementById("td");
    console.log(button);
    button.classList.remove("td");
    button.classList.add("tdHover");

};
```

Espero que te ayude saludos.